How to apply `numpy.finfo` to Polars types?
I sometimes apply numpy.finfo to a Pandas or a NumPy dtype – to determine the maximum support value (max) or the minimum meaningful increment (eps), say. Is there an equivalent for Polars dtypes? Or an easy way to convert a Polars dtype to a NumPy one (without casting the whole array)?

You can use min() and max() on the polars type. On my machine, running the following script:
import polars as pl

print("Unsigned integers")
for t in [pl.UInt8, pl.UInt16, pl.UInt32, pl.UInt64]:
    print(t.__name__, t.min(), t.max())

print("\nSigned integers")
for t in [pl.UInt8, pl.UInt16, pl.UInt32, pl.UInt64]:
    print(t.__name__, t.min(), t.max())

print("\nFloats")
for t in [pl.UInt8, pl.UInt16, pl.UInt32, pl.UInt64]:
    print(t.__name__, t.min(), t.max())

produces the following output:
Unsigned integers
UInt8 0 255
UInt16 0 65535
UInt32 0 4294967295
UInt64 0 18446744073709551615

Signed integers
UInt8 0 255
UInt16 0 65535
UInt32 0 4294967295
UInt64 0 18446744073709551615

Floats
UInt8 0 255
UInt16 0 65535
UInt32 0 4294967295
UInt64 0 18446744073709551615

